# Data Summarization in Apache Pig/Apache Hive For Given Date Range

Tags: hive, apache-pig, hiveql, apache-pig-grunt

I have a requirement where-in i need to do data summarization on the date range provided as input. To be more specific: If my data looks like:

```
Input:
Id|amount|date
1 |10    |2016-01-01
2 |20    |2016-01-02
3 |20    |2016-01-03
4 |20    |2016-09-25
5 |20    |2016-09-26
6 |20    |2016-09-28
```

And If I want the summarization for the month of September, then
I need to calculate count of records on 4 ranges which are:

1. Current Date, which is each day in September.
2. Week Start Date(Sunday of the week as per the current date) to Current Date, Ex. if Current Date  is 2016-09-28 then week start date would be 2016-09-25
   and record counts between 2016-09-25 to 2016-09-28.
3. Month Start Date to Current Date, which is from 2016-09-01 to Current Date.
4. Year Start Date to Current Date,which is record count from 2016-01-01 to Current Date.

So My output should have one record with 4 Columns for each day of the month(in this case, Month is September), Something like

```
Output:

 Current_Date|Current_date_count|Week_To_Date_Count|Month_to_date_Count|Year_to_date_count

 2016-09-25  |1                 |1                 |1                  |4
 2016-09-26  |1                 |2                 |3                  |5
 2016-09-28  |1                 |3                 |3                  |6
```

**Important:** i can pass only 2 variables, which is range start date and range end date. Rest calculation need to be dynamic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can join on year, then test each condition separately (using `sum(if())`):

```
select  a.date, sum(if(a.date=b.date,1,0)), 
                sum(if(month(a.date)=month(b.date) and weekofyear(a.date)=weekofyear(b.date),1,0)),
                sum(if(month(a.date)=month(b.date),1,0)),
                count(*) from
(select * from input_table where date >= ${hiveconf:start} and date <${hiveconf:end}) a, 
(select * from input_table where date <${hiveconf:end}) b 
where year(a.date)=year(b.date) and b.date <= a.date group by a.date;
```

Comment: Thanks Alex!!. But few Points here is:

Comment: Thanks Alex!!. But few Points here is: 1.The weekofyear function considers Monday as the Week Start date. In my case, Sunday needs to be the week start date and  2.the cartesian product runs for ever with minimal data in my base tables, even after using Tez.

Comment: @AKN_1513 you'll then need to implement your own custom weekofyear  UDF. Regarding the speed, try the query that joins on the year.. try only count(*) on the top select, try to find what's causing the delay.

Comment: @AKN_1513 In case you did not realize it, PIG is really not a nice tool for working with calender dates. So yes, you will need to use custom functions or workaround frequently when you try to do 'this kind of stuff'.